# Super() python not working for subclass tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, super

So I have a class, Application, with 2 subclasses MyButton and MyLabel. Application also has

```
self.backgroundcolor = 'orange'
self.textcolor = 'black'
```

I want to use these two variables in my subclasses MyButton and MyLabel. So, I tried

```
class MyButton(Button):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Button.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self['bg'] = super(Application, self).backgroundcolor
        self['fg'] = super(Application, self).textcolor
        self['relief'] = FLAT

class MyLabel(Label):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Label.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self['fg'] = super(Application, self).textcolor
```

but it doesn't work, saying that

```
TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
```

But my Application class looks like

```
class Application(Frame):
    global yearcal
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.month = 5
        self.year = 2014
        self.color_clicked = 'lightskyblue'
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        self.thisyear = now.year
        self.thismonth = now.month
        self.today = now.day
        self.textcolor = 'purple'
        self.bgcolor = 'gray'
        self.today_color = 'palegreen1'
        self.apt_color = 'light coral'
    MORE STUFF HERE...

    class MyButton(Button):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            Button.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
            self['bg'] = super(Application, self).backgroundcolor
            self['fg'] = super(Application, self).textcolor
            self['relief'] = FLAT

    class MyLabel(Label):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            Label.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
            self['fg'] = super(Application, self).textcolor
```

Comment: `MyButton` inherits from `Button`. `Button` inherits from `Application`?

Comment: Button is a predefined tkinter thingy which makes a button. MyButton is a 'customized' version that automatically gives it traits based on Application's variables backgroundcolor and textcolor. Sorry that I can't give a more detailed explanation, since I'm not that good at this. Are you saying that I should do something like Super(application, Super(Button, self))? Hey maybe I should try that.

Comment: No, it didn't work. Probably because Button() is part of tkinter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nested class cant access directly attributes of outer class. You need to do it indirectly, for example:

```
class Application(Frame):
    global yearcal
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.month = 5
        self.year = 2014
        self.color_clicked = 'lightskyblue'
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        self.thisyear = now.year
        self.thismonth = now.month
        self.today = now.day
        self.textcolor = 'purple'
        self.bgcolor = 'gray'
        self.today_color = 'palegreen1'
        self.apt_color = 'light coral'

        # create button and label and pass the application instance 
        # so that they can reference its attributes and methods
        self.my_button = MyButton(self)
        self.my_label = MyLabel(self)



class MyButton(Button):
    def __init__(self, app_instance, *args, **kwargs):
        Button.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self['bg'] = app_instance.backgroundcolor
        self['fg'] = app_instance.textcolor

        self['relief'] = FLAT

class MyLabel(Label):
    def __init__(self, app_instance, *args, **kwargs):
        Label.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self['fg'] = app_instance.textcolor
```

Answer (score 0):

> So I have a class, Application, with 2 subclasses MyButton and MyLabel.

`MyButton` and `MyLabel` do not appear to be subclasses of `Application`. You can only call `super()` to access `Application` from subclasses.

For example, to make `MyLabel` a subclass of `Application`

```
class MyLabel(Application):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            ...
```

Comment: Oh, so it doesn't just work if its nested in the Application? I must sound nooby, but I didn't know that.

Comment: wait what it says name Application is not defined.

Comment: Yes, you have to directly specify that `MyLabel` is inheriting from `Application`. Inheritance only makes sense in some situations. For example, the base class would be `Animal` with various attibutes and methods. Then you have a `Dog` class and a `Cat` class to extend this class. All the methods (i.e. `sleep`)would be defined in the `Animal` class so that you only have to define them once, instead of 50 times (if you had 50 animals)

Comment: But when I try this, it says NameError: name Application is not defined.

Comment: Unindent your classes `MyLabel` and `MyButton`. But I don't think you want to inherit from `Application` now that I see you depend on `Button` and `Label` behaviour as well. Best solution would be to check what @Marcin wrote. His solution will allow your instances to communicate.

Answer (score 0):

In the call to `super()` you have to pass your `type` and "yourself" (self):
so instead of doing:

```
super(Application, self)
```

you should do:

```
super(MyButton, self)
```

Hence the error, `obj must be an instance or subtype of type`:
`self` is not an instance nor subtype of `Application`

Answer (score 0):

There is a confusion in this example between a nested class, which is a class defined within another class, and a subclass, which is a class defined by extending an existing class.

In Python, class inheritance (upon which the super method is based) is accomplished by defining a class with the super class provided as a parameter:

```
class Application(Frame):
    ... #Some class definition

class MyButton(Application):
    ... #MyButton is now a subclass of Application.
```

But this is not what you want, since you want to inherit the behaviour of the Tkinter `Button` and `Label` classes for your `MyButton` and `MyLabel` classes respectively (rather than inheriting the behaviour of the `Application` class.

You original attempt using nested classes doesn't appear as necessarily a bad idea, since it would neatly package all of the behaviour of your class into one place, but it has serious drawbacks which probably aren't what you want.

For a start, you cannot reference an instance of the `Application` class from the nested classes without injecting it in somehow, such as during initialisation. You can, however, access the properties if they are **class** properties, defined in the `Application` class namespace, just like you nested classes. This is probably confusing so here is an example:

```
class Application(object):
    classvar = "Foo" #This is a class level variable

    class NestedClass(object):
        #This is now a nested class, accessed using Application.NestedClass
        def __init__(self, app):

            #This will fail, classvar doesn't exist in this scope
            self.var = classvar

            #This will work if app is an instance of Application
            #Or if app is the class itself
            self.var = app.classvar

            #This will always work, since it references the Application 
            #class directly but it won't capture changes introduced 
            #by an instance of Application, which is what you'll probably do
            self.var = Application.classvar
```

Class level behaviour becomes very confusing due to scoping, and nested classes are **even more confusing** for nothing that can't be gained from implementing every class at the module level.

The best way to inject this kind of requirement is to do it the very way `Tkinter` does it itself. Hand off the `Application` instance as the master of the widget instance it creates. This is shown in Marcin's answer.